# attributeAdded method of ServletContextAttributeListener executes twice when also havin ServletContextListener in the same web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment-descriptor, servletcontextlistener

I'm facing an issue with `ServletContextAttributeListener`.

I have a small java EE web application where I've created a `ServletContextAttribute` :

```
    public class MyServletContextAttributeListener implements ServletContextAttributeListener{

        public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent event){
               System.out.println("Connection attribute added to ServletContext");
        }

        public void attributeRemoved(ServletContextAttributeEvent event){
        }

        public void attributeReplaced(ServletContextAttributeEvent event){
        }

}
```

And I declared my listener in the deployement descriptor as listed below :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.listener.MyServletContextAttributeListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then in a `servlet` which implements a `ServletContextListener`(because I want it to be executed at the deployement of the application) I set an attribute in the `ServletContext` :

```
    public class DatabaseInitializer implements ServletContextListener{

        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
        ...            
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("databaseConnection", connection);
        ...
    }
}
```

I also declared the `ServletContextListener` in the Deployement Descriptor.

The problem is that when I launch my app in `Apache Tomcat`, the `attributeAdded` method is executed twice.  When I remove the ServletContextListener, the `attributeAdded` method runs once.

Can someone explain me why? 
And how do I do to have both my ServletContextListener and my ServletContextAttributeListener both declared in my Deployement Descriptor without that strange behavior?

Comment: Did you see which `attribute` is being added to the `ServletContext`? Print out the names of the `attributes` for which the `attributeAdded` is being called. Print out the names of the attributes using `ServletContextAttributeEvent#getName()`. I don't think the connection is being added twice. Something else might be adding some other thing into the context.

Comment: ok! You're right. I did what you suggested and two different attributes are added to `ServletContext` : the `databaseConnection` attribute that I explicitely defined, and another one called `org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache`. I read javadoc for this and it is a container for tag libraries to be accessed globally in the web app. Since I don't use JSP in my application, is it safe to configure tomcat to not automatically add this attribute? If yes, is there a way to do it not programmatically but by using tomcat configuration files?